# $http.post not working inside ng-click function in Angular Js

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, http-post, ngroute

I'm developing a project with Anjular js and Codeigniter 3. I have faced some issues with routing in angular js. I have a view page with a  list of details of users and inside that list there is a tag with ng-click="myName()". I have declared this function inside my js file and this function works fine.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ListController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1>Starter Template</h1>
            <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change</p>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s" ng-repeat="items in artists">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img ng-src="{{settings.base_url}}/application/assets/images/profile/{{items.shortname}}.jpg" alt="...">

                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>{{items.name}}</h3>
                            <p>{{items.bio}}</p>
                            <p><a href="{{settings.base_url_controller}}auth/functionOne" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myName()" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Inside this function "myName()" I have written $http.post for getting a function inside the controller(Codeiginter controller). I'm using auth.php as controller and functionOne() is the function to retrive.

```
var base_url_abs = window.location.origin;
var base_url = base_url_abs+'/AngularExPack/Angular_Bootstrap_CI_1/';
var base_url_controller = base_url_abs+'/AngularExPack/Angular_Bootstrap_CI_1/index.php/';

    myApp.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', 'settings', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('application/datas/data.json').success(function (data){
    $scope.artists =  data;
  });
$scope.myName = function() {
         alert("hai1");
/*
         $http.post(base_url_controller+'auth/functionOne/').success(function (response){
          $scope.data = response
          console.log(response);
          //alert($scope.data);
        });*/


    /**/ $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : base_url_controller+'auth/functionOne/',
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
         .success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = response
          console.log($scope.data);
          alert($scope.data);
          });

    }

}]);
```

When i run this, an error is occured and showing like this inside the console

[image]

But i'm getting the correct result when i click on this link and also if i give base_url path inside the href inside a tag.

```
<a href="{{settings.base_url_controller}}auth/functionOne" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myName()" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>
```

But what i need is inside this myName function i have to access the controller function functionOne() using $http using angular js. Is that possible.?

**If anyone knows please help me to find out the solution in ng-click. Correct me if i written wrong code.**

Thank you.

Comment: GET works, POST does not. So there is something wrong in your backend.

Comment: Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access so it's a configuration issue

Did you try replacing "window.location.origin;" by a string ?

Comment: @ str

Thanks for ur comment

ReferenceError: response is not defined is showing when i used GET.

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO
Yes buddy still same error is showing.

Comment: I htink i misunderstood , your $http.post isn't to send data ??

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
         $http({
             method  : 'GET',
             url     : base_url_controller+'auth/functionOne/',
             headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
         .success(function(data) {
             $scope.data = data
             console.log($scope.data);
             alert($scope.data);
          });
```

Comment: "ReferenceError: response is not defined" is showing when i used GET.

Comment: the entire view page showing in console but what i need is to load a view page when i click that a tag.

Comment: what do you mean by "load a view page" ? is it an angular view ?

Comment: Not in angular what im saying. it is in codeigniter view.
What my requerment is i have to list 10 user details. each user details contains an a tag to view his/her detail view. In main page im using ng-view and am listing user details in home.php, using .when in angular ngRoute, which i seperated in different folder. This home.php is loaded in ng-view and from this view i have to redirect there detail view page when i click on that a tag. for this im using codeigniter controller for load the detail view page. I think im clear now.

Comment: ok so why not just make a $location.path(base_url_controller+'auth/functionOne/'); in your function ?